# R Sampling with proportions based on labels in the data

Tags: r, dataframe, random, sample

I am trying to sample my dataset with particular logic.
I want to sample my data with certain portions for each labeled id. I wonder if there is this type of option in the sample() function in R

A simple description of my dataset is:

```
       id mode OD_ID
1:  50909    1     1
2:  62024    1     1
3:  82812    1     1
4: 100593    1     1
5: 150391    2     1
6: 159413    2     1
7: 132134    2     1
8: 111111    2     1
9:  78524    3     1
10:802212    3     1
   .
   .
   .
```

**I would like to sample this data with certain ratio of column "mode" within the same id column "OD_ID"**

For example i would like to sample data with columns OD_ID=1, with different ratio of "mode"

**I would like my sampled dataset with mode=1 71% mode=2 21% and mode=3 8%.**
I have more data with sufficient number of rows and I want the sampled data set to have 10 data for each OD_ID. I would also want to round up the number of columns of the samples to the closest integer.

So an example of my output would be

```
      id mode OD_ID
  some id    1     1
  some id    1     1
  some id    1     1
  some id    1     1
  some id    1     1
  some id    1     1
  some id    1     1
  some id    2     1
  some id    2     1
  some id    1     1
   .
   .
   .
  some id    1     2
   .
   .
   .
```

with sampled data of 71% of mode 1 21% of mode2 8% of mode 3 for each pair of OD_ID

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Does your sample size vary? In your example, the sample size is 10. If it is always 10 across groups, then you will always get 7 mode 1, 2 mode 2 and 1 mode 3. Why not just sample 7, 2 and 1 item(s) for mode 1, 2 and 3, respectively?

Comment: @ekoam The sample sizes vary for each labeled "OD_ID"

Answer (score 1):

Consider this function

```
sample_p <- function(lab, n, p) {
  stopifnot(sum(p) == 1)
  p <- p[as.character(unique(lab))]
  p <- p / sum(p)
  sizes <- round(n * p)
  unlist(lapply(names(sizes), function(nm, x, s) {
    sample(x[[nm]], s[[nm]])
  }, split(seq_along(lab), lab), sizes))
}
```

Then you can do something like this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(OD_ID) %>% 
  slice(sample_p(.data$mode, 10, c(`1` = 0.71, `2` = 0.21, `3` = 0.08)))
```

Use this dataframe as an example

```
set.seed(2020)
df <- data.frame(
  id = sample.int(1e6, 200), 
  mode = sample(c(1, 2, 3), 200, T), 
  OD_ID = rep(c(1, 2), each = 100)
)
```

The output looks like this

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   OD_ID [2]
       id  mode OD_ID
    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 779894     3     1
 2 797304     2     1
 3 210680     2     1
 4 753704     1     1
 5 503423     1     1
 6 645002     1     1
 7  27814     1     1
 8 334087     1     1
 9 922379     1     1
10 330177     1     1
11 757881     3     2
12 712945     1     2
13 312035     1     2
14 760862     1     2
15 553939     1     2
16 119729     1     2
17 336224     1     2
18 828775     1     2
19 425781     2     2
20 339844     2     2
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!! though in my situation it returns an error 

Error in grp_n[[as.character(cur_group()$OD_ID)]] : 
  subscript out of bounds

Comment: Have you modified this ```grp_n <- c(`1` = 10, `2` = 20)```? Note that you need to specify the sample size for each OD_ID.

Comment: I have total of 1088 OD_IDs, and I have them in a dataframe. If I want to have the same number of sample for each 1088 OD_IDs how would I write this in the function?

Comment: But you said your sample size varies for each OD_ID. That's why I wrote this function. If the sample size is the same across OD_IDs, then you need a different function. @YunHyunsoo

Comment: I appologize for the  wrong question. How would I assign samples for each 1088 OD_IDs?